# The initialization function of CKEDITOR doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

The function linked with the `instanceCreated` event does not execute.

```
CKEDITOR.replace(elementName,{
   on:{ 'instanceCreated': initFunc,
        'instanceReady': onCompleteFunc
   },
   height: '50%',
   width: 600
});
```

The `onCompleteFunc` function executes like an event handler, however the `intiFunc` function doesn't execute at all. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I managed to accomplish that

```js
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(ev) {
  alert('Editor instance created');
});

CKEDITOR.replace('txtArea');

CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(ev) {
  alert('Editor instance ready');
});
```

```html
<textarea name="txtArea"></textarea>
```

Note: The "instanceCreated" event can't be called after 'ckeditor.replace()' because the instance will have been already created hence this won't run

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmatovu/09hgfamq/): https://jsfiddle.net/bmatovu/09hgfamq/

Comment: No config info should be placed in the instanceCreated event handler? Does the event parameter have an editor component with it?